Finite dimensional Irreps (of algebras) with same traces must be equivalent ('page 136' in Bourbaki)
I look for the reference (or proof) of the following fact which is from appendix (B $27$) of Dixmier's book on $C^*$-algebras.
Claim: Let $A$ be an algebra (not necessarily commutative) over a field $k$ of characteristic zero. Say $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are two irreducible representations in finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces with the property that $\operatorname{Trace}\pi(x) = \operatorname{Trace}\pi'(x)$ for every $x \in A$. Then $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are equivalent.
Attempt: He says this is Prop. 3 on page 136 of the 1958 version of Bourbaki's Algebra, Chapter VIII. I do not have this version of the book. I only have the 2012 version which has no Prop. 3 on page 136. The propositions nearby don't seem to be related. Can someone please help me find this reference? Or point me to a proof from elsewhere? Thank you for reading.

It is a corollary of Lemma 4.1.16 p. 189 in these notes.

@Anne: this is a relatively minor issue, but I don't see any hypotheses on the characteristic in that statement, and it's false in that level of generality. On the final step the division by $\dim V$ requires that the characteristic not divide $\dim V$. In positive characteristic it's possible for the character to vanish identically.

@QiaochuYuan I was wondering the same. My hasty conclusion was that somewhere at the (missing) beginning of these notes (=?), the author (=?) must have written the characteristic will allways be assumed to be $0$. But now, having a closer look at this chapter, it seems that the base field is even (uselessly) assumed to be $\Bbb C$. I like this proof because it uses very few prerequisites (but of course, what is elementary and what is not depends on one's habits).

The notes seem to be Chapter 4 of some edition of Goodman-Wallach 'Symmetry, Representations, and Invariants.' Thank you.

Since $\pi \oplus \pi'$ is finite-dimensional, the intersection $I = \ker \pi \cap \ker \pi'$ has finite codimension, so both representations factor through the finite-dimensional quotient $A/I$. Moreover, since $\pi, \pi'$ are irreducible both representations factor through the further quotient $(A/I)/J(A/I)$ by the Jacobson radical.
This quotient is finite-dimensional and has zero Jacobson radical, so it is semisimple. It follows from the Artin-Wedderburn theorem that we can write
$$(A/I)/J(A/I) \cong \prod_i M_{n_i}(D_i)$$
where each factor corresponds to endomorphisms of a unique irreducible $V_i$, meaning that each factor acts nontrivially on a single irreducible and trivially on all the others. Moreover $\pi, \pi'$ must be two of the irreducibles. So if $\text{tr}(\pi(x)) = \text{tr}(\pi'(x))$ then the two are nonzero on the same $M_{n_i}(D_i)$ (this is where we need that $k$ has characteristic zero) which is only possible if $\pi \cong \pi'$ as desired.
The conclusion can also be strengthened a bit; the argument continues to work if $\pi, \pi'$ are taken to be semisimple, and the multiplicities of the irreducibles are determined by the traces of the centrally primitive idempotents $e_i \in M_{n_i}(D_i)$ given by the identity matrices.

 Since the context is $C^{\ast}$-algebras this is probably not so relevant to you, but the characteristic zero assumption really is necessary. In positive characteristic it can happen that the trace vanishes identically, e.g. if $A$ is a finite product of finite inseparable extensions of $k$.

